# PageSpeed Insights: Server-side rendering or Client-side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, google-crawlers, pagespeed-insights

My website has a conditional accessing rule: if the access is being made by the Googlebot I deliver a page fully rendered by the server (**server-side** rendering).

Otherwise, if the access is being made by a human being I deliver a page with SPA features (**client-side** rendering).

**My question is:** In my last analysis using PageSpeed Insights (Lighthouse) I noticed that the results were based on the **client-side** rendering version. In this case, should I consider that the website performance result will be judged by Google by the **client-side** version?

I'm a little bit confused about this behavior.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Lighthouse is different from googlebot, so probably you are not checking it correctly.

Did a quick check and I found this user agent string my case:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4143.7 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse
```

But in any case: **don't do this**. This tecnique is called **cloaking** and is forbidden by Google.

You risk to have you page removed form the index or heavily penalized.

You must serve to bot what you users normally access to.

Comment: Hello, Keul! 

I use dynamic rendering and Googlebot generally doesn't consider dynamic rendering as cloaking.

Comment: @RafaelaLemos edited my answer with user agent example.

I'm not sure what you mean with dynamic rendering. If you are providing a fully SSR (with a preloader or something like Next.js) why you don't simple always provide the server side rendered version?